# Grails - Adding new default value to an existing Map domain class member

Tags: json, mongodb, grails, web, grails-domain-class

I have the following domain class:

```
class Settings {
    static constraints = {
        uid(nullable: false, unique: true)
        json()
    }

    String uid
    Map json
}
```

I store arbitrary data on the json Map member and my app is already live with data stored on a MongoDB server. Settings data is unique for each app installation.

I would like to add another property to the json map, modifying all my existing data.

---

Example:

**current DB state** `json = {"a":"true"}`

**new DB state** `json = {"a":"true" , "b":"1234"}`

---

What would be the best approach?

- Update Script?
- A change in the domain class?
- Override the domain class constructor?

A code example would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the update operation with multi set to true

   db.collection.update( { }, { $set: { "b":"1234" } },  { multi: true } )
2. If your data set is huge then try to use [server-side javascript](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so I guess your answer is to update the DB manually ... I guess I will use this approach if no other solution will pop

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a database migration tool? Personally, I like [Liquibase](http://grails.org/plugin/liquibase). You could write a SQL migration that inserts a new row into Settings_json (or whatever the generated table name is) for every uid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no I don't, but I will definitely look into that